# Convert camel case to human readable string?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there a reg exp or function that will convert camel case, css and underscore to human readable format? It does not need to support non-humans at this time. Sorry aliens. :(

Examples:

helloWorld -> "Hello World"
hello-world -> "Hello World"
hello_world -> "Hello World"

Comment: Camel case isn't human readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the ActionScript version based on the idea from Ricks C example code. For JavaScript version remove the strong typing. For example, change `var value:String` to `var value`. Basically remove any declaration that starts with a semicolon, `:String`, `:int`, etc.

```
/**
 * Changes camel case to a human readable format. So helloWorld, hello-world and hello_world becomes "Hello World". 
 * */
public static function prettifyCamelCase(value:String=""):String {
    var output:String = "";
    var len:int = value.length;
    var char:String;

    for (var i:int;i<len;i++) {
        char = value.charAt(i);

        if (i==0) {
            output += char.toUpperCase();
        }
        else if (char !== char.toLowerCase() && char === char.toUpperCase()) {
            output += " " + char;
        }
        else if (char == "-" || char == "_") {
            output += " ";
        }
        else {
            output += char;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

JavaScript version:

```
/**
 * Changes camel case to a human readable format. So helloWorld, hello-world and hello_world becomes "Hello World". 
 * */
function prettifyCamelCase(str) {
    var output = "";
    var len = str.length;
    var char;

    for (var i=0 ; i<len ; i++) {
        char = str.charAt(i);

        if (i==0) {
            output += char.toUpperCase();
        }
        else if (char !== char.toLowerCase() && char === char.toUpperCase()) {
            output += " " + char;
        }
        else if (char == "-" || char == "_") {
            output += " ";
        }
        else {
            output += char;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Does `var i:int` need an `= 0`?

Comment: No. Integers initialed to 0 when declared. Oops, yes, in the JS you do. I added a JS example.

Answer (score 33):

Split by non-words; capitalize; join:

```
function toCapitalizedWords(name) {
    var words = name.match(/[A-Za-z][a-z]*/g) || [];

    return words.map(capitalize).join(" ");
}

function capitalize(word) {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: this will also change "test.hello" to "Test Hello". For those who only want case changes, underscores and hyphens use this regex: ```/[A-Za-z][^_\-A-Z]*/g```

Comment: man JS really needs built in method on strings for this. This works just fine but it's fugly and requires your brain to churn for something simple.

Comment: @YungGun How often do people actually want to do this…?

Comment: Also this doesn't work with numbers. This regex `/[A-Za-z][a-z]*|[0-9]+/g` will give you 'addressLine1' => 'Address Line 1'

Answer (score 11):

Extract all words with a regular expression. Capitalize them. Then, join them with spaces.

Example regexp:

```
/^[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*/g

/   ^[a-z]+      // 1 or more lowercase letters at the beginning of the string
    |            // OR
    [A-Z][a-z]*  // a capital letter followed by zero or more lowercase letters
/g               // global, match all instances
```

Example function:

```
var camelCaseToWords = function(str){
    return str.match(/^[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*/g).map(function(x){
        return x[0].toUpperCase() + x.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }).join(' ');
};

camelCaseToWords('camelCaseString');
// Camel Case String

camelCaseToWords('thisIsATest');
// This Is A Test
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is already a built in method to do this but you could loop through the string and every time you see a character that you want to split on do so.

In your case something like:

```
    my_str = 'helloWorld';
    returnString = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < my_str.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            returnString += (my_str[i] + 32); // capitalize the first character
        }
        else if(my_str[i] > 'A' || my_str[i] < 'Z') {
            returnString += ' ' + my_str[i]; // add a space
        }
        else if(my_str[i] == '-' || my_str[i] == '_') {
            returnString += ' ';
        }
        else {
            returnString += my_string[i];
        }
    }

   return returnString;
```

Edit:

After the numerous comments I have come to realize that I put up some broken code :P

Here is a tested version of it:

```
my_str = 'helloWorld';

function readable(str) {
    // and this was a mistake about javascript/actionscript being able to capitalize
    // by adding 32
    returnString = str[0].toUpperCase();

    for(var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        // my mistakes here were that it needs to be between BOTH 'A' and 'Z' inclusive
        if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
            returnString += ' ' + str[i];
        }
        else if(str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '_') {
            returnString += ' ';
        }
        else {
            returnString += str[i];
        }
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Good job, but javascript isn't C.

Comment: `my_str[i] > 'A'` and `my_str[i] < 'Z'` should be `>=` and `<=`

Comment: I'll give you that javascript most likely provides a nicer way to code it up but this still gets the point across. That being said in hindsight my_str[i] + 32 would probably just append 32 to the character in javascript.

Comment: this `(my_str[i] + 32)` is throwing an error. :P i just realized i can use String().toUpperCase().

Comment: Ya, that's probably what @thg435 was referring to. In javascript that would just append 32 to the first character where as in C it would increment the first character by 32, thus capitalizing it.

Comment: the result i'm getting now is "H e l l o W o r l d".

Comment: I've added the JS I converted from your example so far.

Comment: (Uh, I didn’t mean to submit that as a rejection message. Both grammatically incorrect and incomplete. Whoops. Anyways, you can make your own answer, if you like.)

Comment: NP. I'll submit it as another answer. BTW ActionScript is JavaScript plus or minus strong typing. You don't have to use strong types. It was original proposal for EMCAScript 4 but was never approved possibly because it also added packages and classes.

Comment: There also should be a case to capitalize letters following a dash. For the case `hello-world -> "Hello World"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), e.g.

```js
function capitalize(s) {
    return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
}

function replacer1(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, s) {
    return p1 + capitalize(p2) + ' ' + p3;
}

var s1 = "helloWorld";
var r1 = s1.replace(/(^|[^a-z])([a-z]+)([A-Z])/, replacer1);
console.log(r1);
```

`hello-world` and `hello_world` work similar.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pEe5h/1/)

Answer (score 2):

If using a library is an option, `Lodash`'s `startCase` or `lowerCase` might be useful:

https://lodash.com/docs/#startCase

https://lodash.com/docs/#lowerCase

Answer (score 2):

Non elegant one liner using regex replaces with functions.

replace 1 - upper case first letter and remove _-

replace 2 - add space between lower case letters and upper case letters

```js
var titleCase = s => s
  .replace(/(^|[_-])([a-z])/g, (a, b, c) => c.toUpperCase())
  .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, (a, b, c) => `${b} ${c}`);

console.log(titleCase("helloWorld"));
console.log(titleCase("hello-world"));
console.log(titleCase("hello_world"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  const result = _.chain("hello-world")
        .snakeCase()
        .split("_")
        .map(w => _.capitalize(w))
        .join(" ")
        .value()

  console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="
            https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js
            "></script>
```